# Character Selection With Photon PUN2/Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

So I have a simple character selection screen set up - 5 buttons with colors - when a client clicks on a button, that button is not interactable anymore. I also have it so if the player wants a different character, they can click another available one, and then it gets set to non-interactable, and their previous choice is re-enabled. BUT, if another client selects a character, the 1st clients choice get rewritten to whatever client #2 selected.

I have setup an RPC to handle the syncing of choice, but am not sure how to go about fixing it so that each player can select a character.

This is the whole script that handles character selection. The "OnSelect" and "OnClicked" are for the buttons.

```
public class CharacterSelect : MonoBehaviour
{
    PhotonView PV;

    [SerializeField] public Button[] characters;

    private Button lastClicked = null;

    private void Awake()
    {
        PV = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
    }


    [PunRPC]
    public void OnSelect(int id)
    {
        if(lastClicked != null)
        {
            lastClicked.interactable = true;
        }

        characters[id].interactable = false;
        lastClicked = characters[id];

    }

    public void OnClicked(int id)
    {
        PV.RPC("OnSelect", RpcTarget.All, id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you call `OnSelect` on all clients with the same id .... You should probably store the selected Id player wise

Comment: @derHugo could you elaborate? I am semi-new to this, so any more info you could give would be awesome!